# How can I handle dynamic calculated attributes in a model in Django?

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models, django-signals

In Django I calculate the breadcrumb (a list of fathers) for an geographical object. Since it is not going to change very often, I am thinking of pre calculating it once the object is saved or initialized.

1.) What would be better? Which solution would have a better performance? To calculate it at ____init____ or to calculate it when the object is saved (the object takes about 500-2000 characters in the DB)?

2.) I tried to overwrite the ____init____ or save() methods but I don't know how to use attributes of the just saved object. Accessing *args, **kwargs did not work. How can I access them? Do I have to save, access the father and then save again?

3.) If I decide to save the breadcrumb. Whats the best way to do it? I used http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1694/ and have crumb = PickledObjectField().

The model:

```
class GeoObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name',max_length=30)
    father = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name = 'geo_objects')
    crumb = PickledObjectField()
    # more attributes...
```

Thats the method to calculate the attribute crumb()

```
def _breadcrumb(self):
    breadcrumb = [ ]
    x = self
    while True:
        x = x.father
        try:
            if hasattr(x, 'country'):
                breadcrumb.append(x.country)
            elif hasattr(x, 'region'):
                breadcrumb.append(x.region)
            elif hasattr(x, 'city'):
                breadcrumb.append(x.city)
            else:
                break
        except:
            break
    breadcrumb.reverse()
    return breadcrumb
```

Thats my save-Method:

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    # how can I access the father ob the object?
    father = self.father # does obviously not work
    father = kwargs['father'] # does not work either 

    # the breadcrumb gets calculated here
    self.crumb = self._breadcrumb(father)
    super(GeoObject, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Please help me out. I am working on this for days now. Thank you.

Comment: But what is `father`? You say accessing `self.father` *obviously* does not work, but why not? What on earth is it?

Comment: The father is one of the attributes in the model. I added example code of the model now. With obviously i mean, that I can not access the object since it got not saved yet.

Comment: That doesn't follow at all. If you have a father (the usual English word here is parent, but that doesn't matter), that is accessible whether or not you have saved. And if you don't have one, there's nothing in your code that sets one, so you still won't have one after you save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling both the _breadcrumb method with x.father and assigning x = x.father in the beginning of the while loop you jump over one father. Try exchanging

```
self.crumb = self._breadcrumb(father)
```

with

```
self.crumb = self._breadcrumb(self)
```

By defining _breadcrumb within the model class you can clean it up like this:

```
class GeoObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name',max_length=30)
    father = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name = 'geo_objects')
    crumb = PickledObjectField()
    # more attributes...

    def _breadcrumb(self):
        ...
        return breadcrumb

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.crumb = self._breadcrumb()
        super(GeoObject, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

For more complex hierachies I recomend [django-treebeard](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/tip/)